# Working with a dynamic hierarchy SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, recursion, dynamic, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have the following datasets in SQL Server

Hierarchy Table:

```
 Report   |   Immediate Parent
 Child1       Parent1
 Child2       Parent1
 Child3       Parent2
 Parent1      Grandparent1
 Parent2      Grandparent1
```

Data Table (Only exists for Base level children):

```
Report   |   Sales
Child1       1000
Child2       1000
Child3       1000
```

From this I need to create a dataset which contains

```
Report      |   Sales
Parent1         2000
Parent2         1000
Grandparent1    3000
```

---

I do not know how many hierarchy levels there will be, could be great *10 grandparents. My solution to this problem was to use recursion and dynamic SQL to keep creating temporary tables for each hierarchy level i.e.

- Create a temp table for parents, join data table to hierarchy table and sum(sales)
- Create temp table for grandparents, join parent temp table to hierarchy table and sum(sales)
- Rinse and repeat until no rows affected (@@rowcount)
- Merge all temp tables into permanent table

---

However from reading the forums I understand that:

- Recursion is to be avoided,
- Dynamic SQL is to be avoided,
- @@Rowcount is to be avoided

---

My question is, how to approach the problem without using all this bad practice?

Comment: Why to avoid recursive queries? That's the right way to do it here.

Comment: Also why to avoid @@rowcount? Sometimes it's really useful.

Comment: Another potential option is to change your table structure and use nested sets instead of an adjacency list. Here is an article that explains how you can convert your current structure into the nested sets model. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas My understanding is that set based > recursion wherever possible, so my query was whether there is a non-recursion based approach to the problem

Comment: @JamesZ, I had read some comments about deprecation but on further investigation I don't think it's that relevant to this problem

Comment: @Sean Lange, thanks for the link, the article discusses the exact reasons why I hadn't asked for the data to be supplied level based i.e. massive human error potential. In this case I probably don't need to convert to nested sets because the amalgamation itself is pretty speedy, the rowcount isn't likely to balloon and I don't need the extra detail, but definitely useful to know how to do it efficiently

Comment: If you'd like to avoid recursion, you could modify your table a bit and use HierarchyId data type to form child-parent relationship. Later just use built in functionality to join these.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas but wouldn't I need to use recursion to modify the table? i.e. Sean's Comment

Comment: You'd have to use it once, yes.