# Query to select next column if the current column returns no rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

The question is quite extensive, please bear with me. I have a single mapping table with the following structure:

[image]

This particular table is used in the process of generating a hierarchy. The order and position of the columns in the table indicate the order of hierarchy (Organization, Category, Continent, Country.. etc.) Each entity in this hierarchy has a related table with associated `Id` and `Name`. For example, there is a `Country` table with `CountryId` and `CountryName`. Note that since the MappingTable's values are all nullable there are **no foreign key constraints**.

I want to generate a procedure that will do the following:

Based on conditions provided, retrieve values of the next entity in the hierarchy. For example, if the `OrganizationId` and `CategoryId` are given, the values of `ContinentId` that satisfy said condition need to be retrieved.

Also, if the value of `ContinentId` is `NULL`, then the values of `CountryId` need to be retrieved. Here, given the condition `OrganizationId = 1 and CategoryId = 1` the procedure should return the list of `RegionId`.

In addition to retrieving the `RegionId`, the corresponding `RegionName` should be retrieved from the `Region` Table.

So far, the procedure looks something like this - just a few things to explain here.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetHierarchy] 
(
@MappingTableName VARCHAR(30), 
@Position VARCHAR(5),

-- Given in the form of Key-value pairs 'OrganizationId:1,CategoryId:1'
@InputData VARCHAR(MAX), 

@Separator CHAR(1), 
@KeyValueSeperator CHAR(1)
)
AS 
BEGIN   
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(30) 
DECLARE @Exists bit

SELECT @TableName = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @MappingTableName AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @position

SET @TableName = SUBSTRING(@TableName,0,LEN(@TableName) - 1)
-- Returns a dynamic query like "SELECT ContinentId from Continent WHERE OrganizationId = 1 and CategoryId = 1".
SELECT @Sql = [dbo].[KeyValuePairs](@TableName, @InputData, @Separator, @KeyValueSeperator)

SET @Sql1 = N'SET @Exists = CASE WHEN EXISTS(' + @Sql + N' AND ' + @TableName + N'Id IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'

PRINT @Sql

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql1,
                    N'@Exists bit OUTPUT',
                    @Exists = @Exists OUTPUT

IF(@Exists = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @Sql1 = 'SELECT ' + @TableName + 'Id, ' + @TableName + 'Name FROM '+ @TableName+' WHERE ' + @TableName +'Id IN (' +  @Sql + ')';
    PRINT @Sql1
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --PRINT 'NOT EXISTS'
    DECLARE @nextPosition INT
    SELECT @nextPosition = CAST(@position AS INT)
    SET @nextPosition = @nextPosition + 1
    SET @Position =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(@position AS INT))
    EXEC [dbo].[GetHierarchy] @MappingTableName, @Position, @InputData, @Separator, @KeyValueSeperator
END
END
```

The logic of this procedure is such that, I get the name of the column at a particular position (based on the conditions here, it is `Continent`) and generate the dynamic query to retrieve the next column's values based on the condition of the input condition (I am using a separate function to do this for me). 
Once retrieved, I run the query to check if it returns any rows. If the query returns rows, then I retrieve the corresponding `ContinentName` from the `Continent` table. If no rows are returns, I recursively call the procedure again with the next position as the input.

On the business side of things, it seems like a two step process. But, as a procedure it is quite complex, extensive and - not to mention, recursive. Is there an easier way to do this? I am not familiar with CTEs - can the same logic be implemented using CTEs?

This is quite similar to what is asked here: [Working with a dynamic hierarchy SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362529/working-with-a-dynamic-hierarchy-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Might be the little lengthy approach. Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CatId INT,
    Country INT,
    StateId INT,
    DistId INT
)

DECLARE @State TABLE
(
    StateId INT,
    StateNm VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @Country TABLE
(
    CountryId INT,
    CountryNm VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @State
VALUES(3,'FL')

INSERT INTO @Country
VALUES(2,'USA')

INSERT INTO @T(CatId)
VALUES(1)

INSERT INTO @T(CatId,Country)
VALUES(1,2)

INSERT INTO @T(CatId,StateId)
VALUES(1,3)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        IdVal = COALESCE(Country,StateId,DistId),
        IdCol = COALESCE('Country '+CAST(Country AS VARCHAR(50)),'StateId '+CAST(StateId AS VARCHAR(50)),'DistId '+CAST(DistId AS VARCHAR(50)))
        FROM @T
            WHERE CatId = 1
),C2
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo,
        CatId,
        Country,
        StateId,
        DistId,
        IdVal,
        IdCol = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(IdCol,1,CHARINDEX(' ',IdCol))))
        FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    C2.SeqNo,
    C2.CatId,
    S.StateNm,
    C.CountryNm
    FROM C2
        LEFT JOIN @State S
            ON C2.IdCol ='StateId'
                AND C2.IdVal = S.StateId
        LEFT JOIN @Country C
            ON C2.IdCol ='Country '
                AND C2.IdVal = c.CountryId
```